# apache permission denied after changing python shebang

Tags: python, apache, centos6

I'm trying to execute simple python code on my web server. it's like as follow;

index.py file ;

```
#!/home/myenv/bin/python

print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")

print("test is okay")
```

I get the below error from apache;

```
(13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/html/index.py' failed
Premature end of script headers: index.py
```

when i use system-wide python, there is no error from apache.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")

print("test is okay")
```

the above code is working.

I think the problem is about changing shebang but i could'nt solve it.

my web server operating system is CentOS release 6.10

Comment: Is this a mac?  The programs are limited to where on the file system they can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it changing security context of shebang with chcon utility.

This is my solution maybe it can be helped for other people.

```
chcon system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 /home/Python-3.7.9/python
```